# Graph (network) visualization tool

Tags: graphs

I am looking for a simple tool that is able to visualize graphs (networks) presented as a simple weighted edge list:

```
Paris, Oslo, 0.25
Paris, New-York, 0.0001
New-York, Wasington, 0.1
...
```

Where do I get such a tool?

*Target system is:* Linux or online

Answer (score 1):

There are many options available but personally I would use Python 3, (probably already installed on your Linux system), and the [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io) & matplotlib libraries. (Both should be installable with `pip3 install -U NetworkX matplotlib`.

There is a good example [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/auto_examples/drawing/plot_weighted_graph.html).

Comment: There's a good tutorial  at [Graph Optimization with NetworkX in Python](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/networkx-python-graph-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the question’s title:

> ***Graph*** (network) ***vis*** ualization tool

You want [GraphViz](https://graphs.grevian.org).
I have been using it for decades now, and can highly recommend it. It is stable, well documented, and well supported (including 7,277 [questions & answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=graphviz) on Stack Overflow). 
It takes plain text as input and generates diagrams, so your

> Paris, Oslo, 0.25
>   Paris, New-York, 0.0001
>   New-York, Wasington, 0.1

could be easily manipulated to become input.

Perhaps the S.O question [Graphviz, changing the size of edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333025/graphviz-changing-the-size-of-edge) will be poof help?

There is official GraphViz documentation for [Node, Edge and Graph Attributes](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html).
The [GraphViz Pocket Reference](https://graphs.grevian.org/reference) gives

> Edge Attributes
>   •   [label="Some Label"]Labels the Edge (Useful for Weights)
>   •   [color="red"]Colors the Vertex (Useful for Paths)
>   •   [penwidth=2.0]Adjusts the thickness of the edge line, Very useful for Paths

I will confess that I am not a “graph person”, and use it only for diagramming, but here is enough reference to graphs and GraphViz online that I am confident that it is what you are looking for. Please let me know whether I am right or wrong :-)

---

[Update]

a clear [into / tutorial](http://redgreenrepeat.com/2017/01/13/graphviz-quick-intro/), including weighting